# CKEditor's ckbuilder throws exception when build.sh is run

Tags: ckeditor

Following instructions on http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_build I clone the repo from https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev and run `build.sh` in `dev/builder`.

It clones the `ckbuilder` repo and then crashes:

```
Starting CKBuilder...
Exception in thread "main" org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException:
Function importClass must be called with a class; had
"[JavaPackage com.google.javascript.jscomp.CompilationLevel]"
instead. (c:\ckbuilder\src/lib/javascript.js#12)
```

I'm running on OS X with Java 1.6.0_65. I get the same error on a linux machine running basically the same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue. I downloaded the latest version of Java and that handled it for me. Here is JDK 8, the current latest:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html